# Visual Studio PowerShell Making FolderDialog the output folder on the combine script

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-2019

This Is A Windows Form

what i am trying to achieve is:

select an Output Folder using `$folderbrowserDialog1` and then use the `Path` the user has selected to become the `$OutputFolder` in my combine `.pdf` Script see below my `$folderbrowserDialog1` Code

```
###################################### Get Folder 
$button6_Click = {

$folderBrowserDialog1=New-Object System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog
[void]$folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog()
$folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath
$folderBrowserDialog1.ShowNewFolderButton ="true"
$textBox2.Text = $folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath
}
```

and below is my Combine `.pdf` script, where the Hashtags are that's where i need the selected `$folderbrowserDialog1 Path` to be.

i Have tried `$outputFolder = $folderbrowserDialog1.SelectedPath` but no joy

```
$button2_Click = {


$pdftk = "C:\Program Files (x86)\PDFtk Server\bin\pdftk.exe"
$inputFolder = $listbox1.Items
$outputFolder = ########################################

$IntactScan = Get-ChildItem $inputFolder -File | Measure-Object | % {$_.Count}

If ($IntactScan -gt $maxItems) {

   Get-Childitem $inputFolder -filter *.pdf -Recurse 
   pdftk $listbox1.Items cat Output $outputFolder\Rename.pdf

    $listbox1.Items.Clear()

    #Move-Item "E:\SIGNEDNOTES\*.pdf" "E:\Backup\"
}
else {
    exit
}
}
```

Below is what my Windows Form Looks Like

[image]

Comment: `$outputFolder = $textBox2.Text`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen thank you for that much appreciated, couldn't for the life of me see it haha

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen i would also like to rename from within that folder how would i do that my code i have so far `gci "E:\TESTOUTPUT" | rename-item -NewName {$textBox1.Text + ".pdf" }` i need to change the output to the Directory the user selected, i tried $Textbox2.Text but for some reason it renamed the windows Forms

Comment: Specify the new name when calling `Move-Item`: `Move-Item \path\to\some.pdf -Destination (Join-Path $outputFolder "$($textBox1.Text).pdf")`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen out of interest why would i need to use `Move-Item` as the item will already be in the directory the user selected i just need to rename that file while in that directory

Comment: I took your question as to be about moving, then renaming. Searching for "[powershell] rename file" yields more than 2000 results, maybe take advantage of those?

Comment: i have the Rename File bit its just the part of telling the script to rename it from the user's 
`$outputFolder`  selection

Comment: Why not just give it the correct name to start with!? `pdftk $listbox1.Items cat Output "$outputFolder\$($textBox1.Text).pdf"`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen because that would make to much sense ;) thank you for you help